# C++ Base Class As Proxy

Tags: c++, proxy, duplicates, polymorphism, worker

I'm currently running in to an issue figuring out the best way to design my code.

Essentially, I have a class that I want to be extensible with additional functionality. However, the exact way the logic for this class is implemented varies depending on the situation of the program (similar to the policy design pattern).

Since the implementation may vary, I could just setup a series of child classes of my base class, and then add another child to these to add my additional function. However, this would obviously result in a lot of code duplication trying to add the logic for each implementation.

To combat this I've tried use a worker based model, where the base class acts as a proxy to the worker class, allowing for the actual base class itself to be easy to extend. However, I'm still having to write a fair amount of code to essentially duplicate the interface to point to the worker.

I've provided an example of the sort of thing I'm currently doing below:

```
// Interface for workers
class Worker {
public:
    virtual void x() = 0;
    virtual void y() = 0;
    virtual void z() = 0;
};

// This provides the actual implementation
class WorkerChild : public Worker {
public:
    void x() { /*Do thing*/ }
    void y() { /*Do thing*/ }
    void z() { /*Do thing*/ }
};

Worker* getAppropriateWorker() {
    // Some logic here to determine the appropriate type of worker to use
    return nullptr; // Wouldn't actually be nullptr in practice
}

// This acts as something that is easy to instantiate and extend without 
class MyClass {
private:
    Worker* _worker;

public:
    MyClass()
        : _worker(getAppropriateWorker()) {
    }

    void x() { _worker->x(); }
    void y() { _worker->y(); }
    void z() { _worker->z(); }

};

class MyExtendedClass : public MyClass {
public:
    void doAThing() {
        x();
        y();
    }

    void doAnotherThing() {
        z();
        y();
        x();
    }

};
```

As you can see, there's a lot of redefining the interface, and each function in MyClass is just do a simple call to the pointer - the logic isn't being duplicated but it's still slow and annoying.

Does C++ have a better way of dealing with this?

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: what is the purpose of `MyClass` why does `MyExtendedClass` not have a member `Worker` ?

Comment: Oh my god... I am an actual idiot... I have been thiking about this for days and am genuinely concerned I didn't think of that. That is the entire issue sorted, thank you. I've still kept MyClass to allow for polymorphism, but I've just set the _worker to be protected and that solves the entire issue. Thanks for your help, sorry it turned out to be such a stupid question.

Comment: don't worry you are not the only one who has been tricked into believing that inheritance is the solution to everything. Composition over inheritance lets many problems go away